# 7zip batch creates folders instead of filename

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have a simple Windows batch script, which is run by backup software as pre-backup action. It simply looks for latest SQL dumps, compresses them into 10-times smaller 7zip archive, then cloud backup picks it up and sends to cloud storage for archiving.

BATCH creates file name with DATE in front:
**07-10-2018-bak.7z**

But I have problem with BATCH file:

- when I run it manually, it executes just fine and creates filename **07-10-2018-bak.7z** in provided folder
- but when I run it via backup software (as SYSTEM user) as pre-backup action, it instead creates SUB-FOLDERS for each DASH, like this: **`\07\10\2018-bak.7z`**

I did `ECHO` each command line, and it renders just fine.
Even if I run echoed lines manually, they do NOT create folders, but as they should, full filename with date included:

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx7 -stl -y "D:\SQL\Backup-Last-Only\\**07-10-2018-bkp.7z**" "D:\SQL\Backup\SklSistem_FULL_sob.BAK"
```

Any idea where I missed the point?

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del D:\SQL\Backup-Last-Only\*.7z /Q
time/t|find "M" && set t=1,4* || set t=1,3*
for /f "skip=1 tokens=%t%" %%a in ('dir/a-d/tw/o-d D:\SQL\Backup\*FULL*.BAK^|find ":"') do (
 if %%a==%date:~-10% (
  set archdate=%%a
  set archdate=!archdate:.=-!
  "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx7 -stl -y "D:\SQL\Backup-Last-Only\!archdate!-bkp.7z" "D:\SQL\Backup\%%c" 
 ) else goto:eof
)
```

Comment: `time/t|find "M"` returns nothing in my Windows 7 cmd shell.

Comment: If you set `echo on` you will see how the `7z.exe` command line is expanded.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I think the code is intended to determine whether the time format includes AM/PM. Yours doesn't, nor does mine.

Comment: Yes, the line **time/t|find "M" && set t=1,4* || set t=1,3*** gets date from 12 or 24 hour format and in my batch it works perfect. It also works from TaskScheduler. But it seems it has problems running as Pre-Backup action from Online Backup software, because just in this case it does not create archive named 07-10-2018-bak.7z but instead it creates folders structure \07\10\2018-bak.7z.

Comment: @PimpJuice: **YES, that's it!** Batch file running as admin user produces %date% as 08.10.2018, but when run as SYSTEM user via Online Backup app, %date% becomes 10/08/2018. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by a difference in the "***date format***" and the `%DATE%` environmental variable output the script generates when using "*the account you run it from manuall*y" versus the format that's set to with "*the user account which the backup software executes it*".

You just need to use `set archdate=!archdate:/=-!` rather than the `set archdate=!archdate:.=-!` to replace "`/` with `-`" rather than "`.` with `-`" due to the date format difference per the issue you are experiencing that you explain with your current logic.

Furthermore, you should also ***consider using something a bit more universal*** such as `wmic os get LocalDateTime` to set the variable which is not dependent on the date format/locale set per each user account profile—see [Locale-unaware %DATE% and %TIME% in batch files](https://serverfault.com/questions/227345/locale-unaware-date-and-time-in-batch-files) for some detail.

### Script

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del D:\SQL\Backup-Last-Only\*.7z /Q
time/t|find "M" && set t=1,4* || set t=1,3*
for /f "skip=1 tokens=%t%" %%a in ('dir/a-d/tw/o-d D:\SQL\Backup\*FULL*.BAK^|find ":"') do (
 if %%a==%date:~-10% (
  set archdate=%%a
  set archdate=!archdate:/=-!
  "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx7 -stl -y "D:\SQL\Backup-Last-Only\!archdate!-bkp.7z" "D:\SQL\Backup\%%c" 
 ) else goto:eof
)
```

---

### Further Resources

- [How to change date and time formats on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10)
- [Variable Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)